Preliminaries of flat G-bundles with canonical metrics
Recently I've been reading the paper "flat G-bundles with canonical metrics" written by Kevin Corlette, but I have difficulties to understand the basic notions even on the first several pages. For example, what is "a Hermitian metric on $P$ is a fixed reduction of the structure group", what is a "U^{\infty}"-invariant $L^2$-metric and what is a Hamiltonian $U^k$-space? I'm familiar with complex geometry and I know some basic things about principal bundles. Is there any recommendation for me to find a book or lecture note to understand these concepts?
